# Mysql connection over SSL with PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, mysqli

I'm trying to setup PHP mysqli connection to MariaDB database for two VPS servers and need to encrypt the communications due to it being over public network.

Currently I can connect from the client server to database server via commandline mysql client normally and I have checked via tcpdump that the connection is encrypted. However for some reason I can't figure out the PHP part. It's relatively basic nginx + php5-fpm + mariadb setup but mysql is working on non default port.
Debian Jessie, Php5 5.6.7,  Mariadb 10.0.16, nginx 1.6.2

Here's the test script:

```
   <?php
        $DB_NAME = '';
        $DB_HOST = '111.111.111.111';
        $DB_USER = 'username';
        $DB_PASS = 'password';

$mysqli = mysqli_init();
if (!$mysqli) {
    die('mysqli_init failed');
}
//have tried witha and without the following with multiple variations
$mysqli->ssl_set(NULL, NULL, NULL,'/etc/mysql/ssl/',NULL);
if (!$mysqli->real_connect($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME, 11111, NULL,MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL )) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}
        $query = "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'ssl_cipher'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        if($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                        print_r($row);
                }
        }
        else {
                echo 'NO RESULTS';
        }
        mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Main error I'm getting without the ssl_set:

```
2015/07/11 15:58:34 [error] 2857#0: *374 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_connect(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /srv/www/test.php on line 15
PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_connect(): Cannot connect to MySQL by using SSL in /srv/www/test.php on line 15
PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_connect(): [2002]  (trying to connect via tcp://192.168.130.123:42139) in /srv/www/test.php on line 15
PHP message: PHP Warning:  mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002):  in /srv/www/test.php on line 15".....
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. This is really killing me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this problem occurs due to the changes made in PHP 5.6. I guess you are using self-signed certificates? If your DB enables peer_name validation by DEFAULT, there is no way to disable this in PHP. So when generating you certificates you have to use the right "Common Name" for each one:

CA: hostname
Server: FQND, e.g. hostname.example.com
Client: somename

The important part is the server certificate where the Common Name has to be the same as the host you are connecting to.

Comment: Correct. However there's also open bug currently which apparently makes it impossible to use SSL with mysqlnd with self signed certs: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68344
I guess I'm off to autossh land then... It should at least work.

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like is this

> SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

My guess is that you don't have the correct CA set up. Some DB systems (like Amazon Web Services RDS) have their own CA file. You're using the `capath` argument so make sure the PEM files are in that path. If they are, the next thing I would do is switch to [the third argument of ssl_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php) and specify the PEM file directly

```
$mysqli->ssl_set(NULL, NULL, '/path/to/ca.pem', NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try with ssl_set so that I specified the files directly, and with the path only and without the whole ssl_set... No dice. Also as PHP should be using mysql client and the mysql client has been tested to work already I don't understand why php suddenly complains about CA problems. Does the mysqli client not use mysql client but something else?

Comment: @Tuxie Depends on you config. Some servers still use mysql-client to connect to MySQL while others use `mysqlnd` (which is the preferred). If you can, go get [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) and try to connect to your server that way (provided you can access it from your desktop). It uses the same SSL connection options and could possibly tell you if something else was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I guess I'll have to check out mysqlnd a bit more in detail. So far I thought it'd use mysql client but it might do something entirely different.

Comment: @Machavity Thanks for your answer. Could you clarify something for me? I'm trying to connect to RDS via SSL (SSL is required for the db user), but it doesn't seem to matter what value I set for the third parameter of ssl_set(), as long as the parameter is not NULL. When I print the output of "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'ssl_cipher'" I can see that I am indeed connected via SSL whether the the third parameter is the true path or just "a". Is this expected? Could you give me a brief explanation due to my limited understanding of SSL? Thanks!

Comment: @JackHumphries Sounds like an excellent question to post by itself

Comment: @Machavity Already did that :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823926/how-to-connect-to-amazon-rds-via-ssl