# How to connect to Amazon RDS via SSL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ssl, amazon-rds

I'm trying to set up an SSL connection to a MySQL database hosted via Amazon RDS. I'm confused as to how to connect.

According to Amazon's [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html), I need to download a CA certificate called "rds-ca-2015-root.pem" and use it in my SSL connection. **I set the database user that I am connecting with to require SSL.**

In PHP, I include the code below to initiate the connection:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options($mysqli, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
$mysqli->ssl_set(NULL, NULL, "/path/to/pem", NULL, NULL);
$mysqli->real_connect("host", "username", "password", "name", 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
```

**However, no matter which path I specify as the third parameter in ssl_set() (even if the path is invalid), an SSL connection is successfully established. The third parameter just can't be set to NULL.**

I verify this by running this query: `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';`. The output verifies that the connection is encrypted (Ssl_cipher => AES256-SHA).

Could someone please explain to me how this works? I am confused as to why the connection continues to work successfully when the path is incorrect. How is the RDS server being verified?

Comment: If you are running this on a Unix machine depending on the flavor and configuration of OpenSSL you are using there is a directory that holds your system wide certificates. Openssl will look to that path for an appropriate certificate. What is not clear here is (assuming you are on a unix machine) whether or not you've placed your cert in that directory. If you've made a successful connection you must have. You can get more information on specific directory locations here: http://serverfault.com/questions/62496/ssl-certificate-location-on-unix-linux

Comment: I've done quite a bit of testing here (from an EC2) instance and it looks like the line that sets the PEM public key path isn't even required, nor are the lines to include the PEM from the AWS docs for connecting via command line. This implies that @mba12 is correct in that the RDS certificates must exist in the instance somewhere already and not need to be referenced. If I reference them incorrectly then yeah, it breaks. Are you testing this from outside an AWS VPC?

Comment: @RobbieAverill It's been a year or so since I've used AWS regularly but when I did I always used a PEM file and specified a path. I've never tried to integrate the PEM file into openssl specifically for AWS. But for other generic linux boxes putting certs into the OpenSSL default directory worked well. You just have to be careful about getting your particular box's openssl configuration correct. That was the only thing gave me a little bit of an issue. As I mentioned openssl comes in a couple of flavors.

Comment: @Jack Humphries, you got a lot of follow/up questions here now. It would be nice if you could answer them so we can try to answer your question,.

Comment: where you upload you .pem files on server?

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your responses. I don't see the PEM file in any of the expected directories on the server, so I don't *think* that it's already on the server. The thing I'm having trouble understanding is why the connection is successful even when the certificate I reference is invalid or when the path is invalid. Any ideas? Is there anything you want me to try?

Answer (score 1):

The RDS documentation actually explains why this is happening, and suggests that you don't even need the CA cert:

> Amazon RDS began updating the SSL certificates on all DB instances on
>   March 23, 2015, but did not initiate a reboot of the instances. No
>   operational impact or downtime is incurred when these updates are
>   performed, and in many situations we will perform the update in your
>   maintenance window. Amazon RDS will not update the certificate for
>   your instances if you have already performed the update. Also note
>   that Amazon RDS is not updating the certificates in AWS GovCloud (US)
>   and the China (Beijing) regions.
>
> Regardless of whether you manually update the certificate or Amazon
>   RDS updated the certificate, the DB instance must be rebooted for the
>   new certificate to take effect. You can decide when you want to
>   manually reboot the DB instance, but you must update the certificate
>   and reboot the instance before the old certificate (rds-ca-2010)
>   expires on April 3, 2015.
>
> You can check the certificate authority (CA) being used by your DB
>   instance using the Amazon RDS console. The CA is listed under the
>   Security and Network section of your DB instance details. If your
>   instance shows rds-ca-2015, then the new certificate has been
>   successfully applied. You still need to reboot your database instance
>   and update your client application to use the new SSL certificate.
>
> If the Amazon RDS console shows your instance CA as rds-ca-2010, then
>   the new certificate has not been applied to your database instance
>   yet. Use the instructions following to update the SSL certificate on
>   your database instances.

The 3rd parameter is essentially being ignored by the client. I'm betting by setting the 3rd param to `NULL`, there is no point in calling `mysqli::ssl_set()` if all the params are null.

Try removing that function call altogether.

Comment: Your quote from the RDS documentation refers to the *server* which in no way describes why his php code, running as a client on an EC2 instance, is successfully connecting to the server in spite of his `ssl_set` calls.  The OP question is about the *client* which is connecting, not about RDS.

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell - if you ask for or require an SSL connection to RDS MySQL you will get one - regardless of whether the local copy of the certificate is valid or readable.

I am using the following config in Drupal and regardless of where or what I put in the cert path I get an SSL connection:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = [
  'database' => 'drupal_db',
  'username' => 'db_user',
  'password' => 'db_password',
  'host' => 'hostname',
  'port' => '3306',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'prefix' => '',
  'pdo' => array(
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/etc/ssl/certs/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem',
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false,
  ),  
];
```

However, if I set the MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT value to "false" I get a connection error and Drupal fails. So far I have not been able to find any explanation of why this won't validate the certificate an/or how to make it successfully do so!