# Connect to AWS mysql over SSL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, connection

I am trying to connect to (remote) AWS MYSQL database using php and ssl.

1. I created a database user and could connect with it from php and also on console.
2. Then I modified the user to use SSL with ***"require ssl"*** in the database.
3. I can stil connect on the console by:
   ***mysql -h host -u username -p --ssl***

But in php I get an ERROR 2002.

```
$con=mysqli_init();
mysqli_ssl_set($con,NULL,NULL,"cacert.pem",NULL,NULL);
$link = mysqli_real_connect($con, "host", "username", "password");
```

As far as I know the ssl_set parameters doesn't matter with AWS databases.
[How to connect to Amazon RDS via SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823926/how-to-connect-to-amazon-rds-via-ssl)

I think it has to do with the mysqli_ssl_set method, without it a connection is made and access is denied by database and this is the correct behaviour. It might be some configuration error on client side, but I have no idea what I shoud check.

The error is fired by mysqli_real_connect, as mysqli_ssl_set always returns true, just after it tries to connect will it receive an error.

Comment: Getting a [2002](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_connection_error) error is a bit odd.

Comment: Well I am getting it. I think it has to do with the mysqli_ssl_set method, without it a connection is made and access is denied by database and this is the correct behaviour. I might be some configuration error on client side, but I have no idea what I shoud check.

Comment: The odd bit is that the message associated with a 2002 error is *Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '%s' (%d)*. Maybe getting the full message (particularly what `%s` and `%d` are set to) might help.

Comment: It is definately odd. I have to admit I am new with php and I can't get a mysql error message only number. If I read the php error message I only get: **Array ( [type] => 2 [message] => mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): [file] => /var/www/html/test.php [line] => 11 )** where line 11 is where I call mysqli_real_connect

Comment: What about when you use `mysqli_error` to get the last error?

Comment: This is the code, what I am trying to use to see the mysql error.
'$link = mysqli_real_connect($con, ...);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
}'

Comment: It's also a good idea to update your original question with things you try and additional detail as you encounter it.

Comment: I tried mysqli_error. And I get a php error _invalid object or resource mysqli_. Is it because no connection was made yet?

Comment: I guess so. Have you tried connecting via SSL using a Commandline client, just to be sure it's working? HeidiSQL seems to have good support for SSL

Comment: It works on the command line using the command which I described in the question. I have to use the **--ssl** tag, without it I get the _Access denied_ error, and this is how it should work.

Comment: Are the certificate permissions ok? Would the PHP code work if you called it via the command line?

Comment: So I tried to execute it via ommand. First I got an error: _could not load cacert.pem_. Seems that this parameter does matter.   After this I downloaded the aws certificate and gave the correct path as parameter. Now it works via command but still doesn't via browser. Can you tell me where I can check/set these permissons?

Comment: In linux under apache I'd do `chown www-data:www-data /path/to/cacert.pem` and then `chmod 644 /path/to/cacert.pem` (not sure about the 2nd one, maybe it should be `400` instead).

Comment: I tried changing ownership to apache:apache and also myuser:apache (apache = www-data in centos, which I am using). Also tried changing permission to 644 and 777 which basicly grants read/write/exec for everybody. Still the same error, it works via console but doesn't via browser. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you think I should start a new question for this? Because the answer to my original question is, that a valid ca path is required as parameter, I guess...

Comment: Might be worth asking a new question. Just incorporate everything you did up to now as well and probably delete this question too.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed it did not work for me until I specified the port.  The following worked:

```
    $db = mysqli_init();
    $db->options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
    $db->ssl_set(NULL, NULL, 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem', NULL, NULL);        
    $db->connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, 3306);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$servername = "only-ssl-db.ct5b4uz1gops.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$con = mysqli_init();
if (!$con){
die("mysqli_init failed");
}
mysqli_ssl_set($con,NULL,NULL,'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem',NULL,'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA'); 

if (!mysqli_real_connect($con,$servername, $username, $password, $dbname))
{
  die("Connect Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Some queries...
echo "Database connected";
printf("Client version: %d\n", mysqli_get_client_version());
mysqli_close($con);
```